# Check if .tar.gz file is currently being extracted

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, command-line-interface, command-line-arguments

Is there a way to see if a .tar.gz file is currently being extracted? I'm currently downloading some very large databases and am unsure whether the process crashed/aborted or is still running. The file in question is almost 300GB and will be 4TB if successfully extracted. However, there is no progress being shown in the bash terminal and it has been at work for over 1 hour now, which is longer than what the download took.

It's also worth of note that the storage this is file is on is NVME but I don't know the exact hardware installed

Comment: If extraction is happening into directory `D` that nothing else is using: `touch timestamp; sleep 10; find D -newer timestamp` will show you anything that has changed in the last 10 seconds. It's not hugely efficient but that may not be a problem as a one-off.

Comment: probably with the help of `ps -ef` and `top` or `htop` commands if on linux environment.

Comment: Thanks to everyone in this thread! I was able to verify the unpacking process was still working using htop

Answer (score 0):

If lsof (list open files) is installed, You could try `lsof | grep tar` to see if it is still extracting.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure the **integrity of the file transfer**, the best way is to use "**rsync**" with the appropriate options.  *Otherwise, you need to do a separate checksum at both source and copy to compare and confirm they are identical*.  Command format would be

```
rsync --checksum ...
```

If you are trying to confirm whether the downloading **process is still live**, then searching for the known process on the "**ps**" report will confirm that it is still running.  Depending on your need, the command format would be

```
ps -ef | grep rsync
```

*At the end of this, you will find a handy script I wrote to monitor progress of a single active rsync job (no parallel jobs).*

If you want to **monitor the destination directory** (*reserved uniquely for this download process*) for specific insights of *file-related OS actions*, you could do that with the "**inotifywait**" utility, which would also report to you both the temporary and permanent filenames, if you use the correct options.  The command format would be something like this:

```
inotifywait -m --format '%:e %f' /tmp
```

The output looks like this:

```
Setting up watches.
Watches established.
CREATE dum.txt
OPEN dum.txt
MODIFY dum.txt
CLOSE_WRITE:CLOSE dum.txt
MOVED_FROM dum.txt      (if that was a temporary name)
MOVED_TO dum2.txt
```

**Script to monitor "rsync"**:

```
#!/bin/sh

##########################################################################################################
### $Id: OS_Admin__partitionMirror_Monitor.sh,v 1.3 2022/08/05 03:46:55 root Exp root $
###
### This script is intended to perform an ongoing scan to report when an active RSYNC backup process terminates.
##########################################################################################################

redON="\033[91;1m"
redOFF="\033[0m"

greenON="\033[92;1m"
greenOFF="\033[0m"

cyanON="\033[96;1m"
cyanOFF="\033[0m"

italicON="\033[3m"
italicOFF="\033[0m"

yellowON="\033[93;1m"
yellowOFF="\033[0m"

. $Oasis/bin/INCLUDES__TerminalEscape_SGR.bh

BASE=`basename "$0" ".sh" `
TMP="/tmp/tmp.${BASE}.$$"

date | awk '{ printf("\n\t %s\n\n", $0 ) ; }'

if [ "$1" = "--snapshots" ]
then
    SNAP=1
else
    SNAP=0
fi

rm -f ${TMP}
ps -ef 2>&1 | grep -v grep | grep rsync | sort -r >${TMP}


if [ ! -s ${TMP} ]
then
    echo "\t RSYNC process is ${redON}not${redOFF} running (or has already ${greenON}terminated${greenOFF}).\n"
    exit 0
fi

awk '{ print $2 }' <${TMP} >${TMP}.pid


awk '{ printf("%s|%s\n", $3, $2) }' <${TMP} >${TMP}.ppid


for pid in `cut -f1 -d\| ${TMP}.ppid `
do
    PPID=`grep ${pid} ${TMP}.pid `
    PID=`grep '^'${pid} ${TMP}.ppid | cut -f2 -d\| `
    PRNT=`grep '^'${pid} ${TMP}.ppid | cut -f1 -d\| `
    if [ \( -n "${PPID}" \)  -a  \( "${PRNT}" -ne 1 \) ]
    then
        descr="child"
        echo "\t PID ${PID} is RSYNC ${cyanON}${italicON}${descr}${italicOFF}${cyanOFF} process ..."
    else
        descr="MASTER"
        echo "\t PID ${PID} is RSYNC ${yellowON}${descr}${yellowOFF} process ..."
    fi
done

getRsyncProcessStatus()
{
    testor=`ps -ef 2>&1 | awk -v THIS="${PID}" '{ if( $2 == THIS ){ print $0 } ; }' `
    MODE=`echo "${testor}" |
        awk '{ if( $NF ~ /^[/]DB001_F?[/]/ ){ print "2" }else{ print "1" } ; }' 2>>/dev/null ` 
}

getRsyncProcessStatus

if [ ${MODE} -eq 2 ]
then
    echo "\t RSYNC restore process under way ..."
    INTERVAL=60
else
    echo "\t RSYNC backup process under way ..."
    INTERVAL=10
fi

if [ -n "${testor}" ]
then
    echo "\n\t ${testor}\n" | sed 's+--+\n\t\t\t\t--+g' | awk '{
        rLOC=index($0,"rsync") ;
        if( rLOC != 0 ){
            sBeg=sprintf("%s", substr($0,1,rLOC-1) ) ;
            sEnd=sprintf("%s", substr($0,rLOC+5) ) ;
            sMid="\033[91;1mrsync\033[0m" ;
            printf("%s%s%s\n", sBeg, sMid, sEnd) ;
        }else{
            pLOC=index($0,"/DB001_") ;
            if( pLOC != 0 ){
                sBeg=sprintf("%s", substr($0,1,pLOC-1) ) ;
                sEnd=sprintf("%s", substr($0,pLOC) ) ;
                printf("%s\033[1m\033[93;1m%s\033[0m\n", sBeg, sEnd) ;
            }else{
                print $0 ;
            } ;
        } ;
    }'
    echo "\n\t Scanning at ${INTERVAL} second intervals ..."
    test ${SNAP} -eq 1 || echo "\t \c"
fi

if [ ${SNAP} -eq 1 ]
then
    while true
    do
        getRsyncProcessStatus
        if [ -z "${testor}" ]
        then
            echo "\n\n\t RSYNC process (# ${PID}) has ${greenON}completed${greenOFF}.\n"
            date | awk '{ printf("\t %s\n\n", $0 ) ; }'
            exit 0
        fi
        jobLog=`ls -tr /site/Z_backup.*.err | tail -1 `
        echo "\t `tail -1 ${jobLog}`"
        sleep ${INTERVAL}
    done 2>&1 | uniq
else
    while true
    do
        getRsyncProcessStatus
        if [ -z "${testor}" ]
        then
            echo "\n\n\t RSYNC process (# ${PID}) has ${greenON}completed${greenOFF}.\n"
            date | awk '{ printf("\t %s\n\n", $0 ) ; }'
            exit 0
        fi
        echo ".\c"
        sleep ${INTERVAL}
    done 
fi
```

Snapshot of terminal session while the script is running:

[image]